# is there a way to change case to low or high whole block in visual mode vim?

Tags: vim

Want to change case to lower in whole block in visual mode. 
If i want to change case of a single character, i can press ~, but what i need to use in visual mode for changing in selected area into low or high case ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- The `~` also works on visual blocks and 'inverts' the casing (lowercase becomes uppercase, uppercase becomes lowercase)
- `u` makes the selection lower case (regardless on the original casing)
- `U` makes the selection upper case (regardless on the original casing)

Answer (score 5):

The `~` command works on a visually selected block as well.

For example, if you:

1. Press `v` to enter visual mode
2. Highlight the area of text to modify
3. Press `~`

It changes the case of all the highlighted text.

Answer (score 5):

With visual selection active, press 'u' for lowercase, 'U' for uppercase.

Without visual mode, use 'gu' or 'gU', with motion command. E.g. to uppercase a word 'gUw'.